# Difference between global buttons and context sensitive buttons related to a data table

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation

I have a table of students with data.

I would like to make it more obvious to the user that the **last two buttons** can only be used in the context of selected row(s).

For that I would of course enable/disable the buttons when no Row is selected.

But that is not enough IMHO. I would like to re-locate those 2 buttons more to the table where the context is.

How would you do that?

I also like material design from google, but there is nothing about context buttons to the table: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-specs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some suggestions to the current design:

- Place related controls close to the context: Add/Remove/Clear are
  close to the table, and the Classes and Subjects are on the perephery
- Remove icons, they looks not so distinctive and if the icon fonts
  will not load, user will see 'Student' and 'Students' actions,
  instead of the intended 'Add Student' and 'Remove Student'
- Simplify
  the table by combining the both names under the single Student
  column, and remove ID. ID is internal piece of data
- Use pale colors
  for the subjects, otherwise these draw too much attention

I think something like this looks more simple and will work better:

[image]

Comment: To 1) Thanks for the mockup. To 2) The icons did not look distinctive because Remove/Delete/Clear have nearly same icons which will change finally. To 3) Of course its just WIP Id will be removed later. To 4) Colors are determined by the teacher itself. They choose the colors they want ;-) The "X" on the subjects is to delete a single subject. Because with "Clear subjects" you can only delete ALL subjects of a selected student.

Comment: Are Remove and Clear Subjects grey because nothing is selected? If yes how would you color them if I select a Row? Also blue like the "Add Student" ?

Comment: @Pascal yes and yes